# Calculate daily Sales budget from a monthly number based on daily sales Percentage.

Tags: functions, finance, economics

### Background

I am working on a problem for a rudimentary business intelligence initiative.  I'm in IT by trade, so this level of mathematics is a bit of a stretch for me.

### Problem

Finance projects sales on a monthly basis.  I want to break it down to a daily sales number, with a nod to the average percent sales on a given day of the week.

**Sample input data**

- $S = $ Month sales projection: $50,000$
- $[DP]=$ Percent sales based on day of week

| Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $18$ | $19 $ | $20$ | $22$ | $21$ |

- $[DN] = % $ Number of each sales day in month:

| Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $4$ | $4$ | $4$ | $4$ | $5$ |

### My Attempts

First, I've done two different routes to get a 'workable' answer, but I'm not satisfied.  Both involve an error correction step, which is my indicator that this is not the correct method.

**Attempt #$1$**

$[X] = \frac{[DN]}{Average[DN]}(S\cdot [DP])$

$[Y] = (S-sum([X])\cdot [DP] $

Daily Budget $= \frac{([X] + [Y])}{[DN]}$

**Result**
| Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa |
|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|
| $0$ | $0$ | $2137.5$ | $2256.25$ | $2375$ | $2612.5$ | $2495$ |

**Attempt #$2$**

$ X = (\frac{S}{sum([DN]})\cdot(1+DP-Average[DP])\cdot[DN] $

$ [Y] = (S-sum([X])\cdot [DP] $

Daily Budget $= \frac{([X] + [Y])}{[DN]}$

**Result**
| Su | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa |
|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|:---|
| $0$ | $0$ |$2332.26$|$2356.01$ | $2379.76$ | $2427.26$ | $2403.76$ |

### Desired Result

Numerically, I don't know what the correct numbers should be. But eliminating the error correction step (the $[Y]$) seems like a good idea.

Thank you for any input you may have.